# Function =VLOOKUP(MAX(B5:B11);A4:B11;1;1) Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, vlookup, vba

I need to get title of the cell to the left of the higher value of the column.

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(B5:B11);A4:B11;1;1)
```

I use this command, but return:  #N/A!
[This is the capture of the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF5A1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an approximate match for the range_lookup parameter of the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). An approximate match can only be performed on sorted data.

Additionally, you need an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair when the lookup column is to the right of the retrieved data.

```
=INDEX(A$4:A$11; MATCH(MAX(B5:B11); B$4:B$11; 0))
```

A better method may be to also retrieve the column of data from B5:G11 using a match to the column header labels in B4:G4 from A15:A20.

[image: MAX INDEX]

Your maximum formula in G15 would be,

```
=MAX(INDEX($B$5:$G$11; ; MATCH(A15; $B$4:$G$4; 0)))
```

To retrieve the associated comments, use this in B15,

```
=INDEX($A$5:$A$11; MATCH(G15; INDEX($B$5:$G$11; ; MATCH(A15; $B$4:$G$4; 0)); 0))
```

Fill the two formulas down to retrieve the results in the other rows.

---

<sub>btw, the highlighting in the sample image was created using a conditional format for B5:G11 based on the formula `=B5=MAX(B$5:B$11)`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Jeeped.
I'm testing with your tips.
I back to tell you my success or failure.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped. Learned a lot from you, I could do what needed.